# Find the earliest repeated date in array

Tags: javascript

Trying to find the earliest most repeated date in an array. The following should return 2017-06-20 but it returns 2017-06-21

```
const arr = [
  '2017-06-17',
  '2017-06-18',
  '2017-06-19',
  '2017-06-20',
  '2017-06-20',
  '2017-06-21',
  '2017-06-21',
  '2017-06-22',
  '2017-06-23',
];

const test = (arr) => {
  return arr
    .sort(
      (a, b) =>
        arr.filter((val) => val === a).length -
        arr.filter((val) => val === b).length
    )
    .pop();
};
```

Comment: Is the array always sorted like that or not?

Comment: No, not always sorted

Comment: The two `2017-06-21` values get sorted to the very end of your array here. They occur with the same _frequency_ as `2017-06-20` - but you neglected to use the actual date order as a _second_ order criterion here, for those elements that have the same count.

Comment: @user3214545 Ok then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function which, given an array, sort it then search for the earliest repeated date by comparing each date with the previous one, *e.g.*. `getEarliestRepeatedDate`.

**UPDATE:** I have updated my code with another function, `getEarliestMostRepeatedDate`, which, given an array, returns the earliest most repeated date.

```js
let arr = [
  '2017-06-17',
  '2017-06-18',
  '2017-06-19',
  '2017-06-20',
  '2017-06-20',
  '2017-06-21',
  '2017-06-21',
  '2017-06-21',
  '2017-06-22',
  '2017-06-23',
];
console.log(getEarliestRepeatedDate(arr));
console.log(getEarliestMostRepeatedDate(arr));

function getEarliestRepeatedDate(arr) {
  arr.sort();
  if (arr.length > 1) {
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i] == arr[i - 1]) {
        return arr[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function getEarliestMostRepeatedDate(arr) {
  let arr2 = [];
  arr.forEach(date => {
    let isInArr2 = false;
    arr2.forEach(date2 => {
      if (date == date2.date) {
        isInArr2 = true;
        date2.repetition++;
      }
    });
    if (!isInArr2) {
      arr2.push({
        date: date,
        repetition: 1
      });
    }
  });
  let maxRepetition = 1;
  let earliestMostRepeatedDate = null;
  arr2.forEach(date2 => {
    if (date2.repetition > maxRepetition) {
      maxRepetition = date2.repetition;
      earliestMostRepeatedDate = date2.date;
    }
  });
  return earliestMostRepeatedDate;
}
```

Comment: The above returns the repeated earliest date but I need the earliest most repeated date so if the array has 2 repeated values and a value repeated 3 times, it should return the one repeated 3 times, so for an array like the following, it should give back 2017-06-21

let arr = [
  '2017-06-17',
  '2017-06-18',
  '2017-06-19',
  '2017-06-20',
  '2017-06-20',
  '2017-06-21',
  '2017-06-21',
  '2017-06-22',
  '2017-06-23',
];

Comment: @user3214545, you didn't say about that in your question, do you want to return the most reapeated or the early date?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, that it what I need: the most repeated or the early date...i will update question

Comment: @user3214545 I have edited my code  to answer your question

Answer (score 3):

With a sorted array, you could just seach for the earliest same following pair.

```js
const
    array = ['2017-06-17', '2017-06-18', '2017-06-19', '2017-06-20', '2017-06-20', '2017-06-21', '2017-06-21', '2017-06-22', '2017-06-23'],
    result = array.find((value, i, { [i - 1]: prev }) => value === prev);

console.log(result);
```

For unsorted data, you need to sort in advance and use the above code or take a `Set` for seen values and reduce the array.

```js
const
    array = ['2017-06-21', '2017-06-21', '2017-06-22', '2017-06-23', '2017-06-17', '2017-06-18', '2017-06-19', '2017-06-20', '2017-06-20'],
    result = array.reduce(
        (s => (r, v) => {
            if (s.has(v) && (!r || v < r)) return v;
            s.add(v);
            return r;
        })
        (new Set),
        undefined
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok as per your request I have edited my code to get you
the most early repeated date instead of just the early one
and I have changed the array too to demonstrate that

```js
const arr = [
  '2017-06-19',
  '2017-06-21',
  '2017-06-18',
  '2017-06-20',
  '2017-06-23',
  '2017-06-21',
  '2017-06-20',
  '2017-06-22',
  '2017-06-17',
  '2017-06-21',
];

function getTheEarlyMostRepeatedDate(arr) {
  var r = {}, date = "", max = 0;
  arr.forEach(function(e) {
    r[e] = typeof r[e] !== "undefined" ? r[e] + 1 : 0;
  });
  for(a in r) {
    if(max < r[a]) {
      date = a;
      max = r[a];
    } 
  }
  return date;
}

console.log(getTheEarlyMostRepeatedDate(arr));
```